# Using redirects in Okta and Xamarin.Forms

Tags: android, authentication, xamarin.forms, okta, okta-api

so I am making an app with xamarin.forms that uses [This](https://github.com/oktadeveloper/okta-appauth-xamarin-example) Example to authenticate. It works super well for my purpose on IOS but on android, I get this [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0CPy.jpg) It's just stuck and won't redirect to the next page. I check this [Issue](https://github.com/okta/okta-sdk-appauth-android/issues/8). But I don't know how to fix this I am basic at Xamarin.Forms and Okta

Comment: Were you able to solve your issue? I am in the exact same situation... Any update would be greetly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Its a bit of a problem i found a way can you contact me on discord so I can help you my username is jojoosinga#3815